# html names don't match

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have this html code:

```
        <c:forEach items="${config.sources}" var="source" varStatus="sourceStatus">
            <form:checkbox path="sources[${sourceStatus.index}].selected" 
            label="${source.sourceName}" 
            name="${sourceStatus.index}"
            onclick="toggle(this)"/>
            <br />
            <c:forEach items="${source.feeds}" var="feed" varStatus="status">
                <c:if test="${feed.display == true }">  
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <form:checkbox path="sources[${sourceStatus.index}].feeds[${status.index}].selected" name="${sourceStatus.index}"/>
                    <c:out value="${feed.name}" /> (provided by ${feed.provider})
                <br />
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
```

What it does is make a bunch of checkboxes, where if the "main" checkbox becomes selected, it call the javascript method "toggle", which should select all the "sub" checkboxes for that "main" checkbox.  Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(chkbox) {

    if (chkbox.checked) {
            var x = document.getElementsByName(chkbox.name);
            for ( var i in x) {
                if (!x[i].checked)
                    x[i].click();
                alert("HEY!" + x[i].name);
            }
        } else if (!chkbox.checked) {
            var x = document.getElementsByName(chkbox.name);
            for ( var i in x) {
                if (x[i].checked)
                    x[i].click();
                alert("HEY!" + x[i].name);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

However, while the "main" checkbox get's checked, none of its "sub" boxes get checked. Furthermore, when the alert goes off after the "main" has been selected, only ONE alert goes off, presumably for the "main" box, and it does not print out an index like expected, instead it says, "sources[X].selected" where X is the index.  Furthermore, when deselected, it has four alerts, regardless of the number of "sub" boxes.  They always say, "sources[X].selected", "undefined", "item", and "namedItem", respectively.  WTH is going on??!  I must be doing something very wrong.

Comment: SO answers are quick if your question is worded well, you show effort, and someone happens along that is knowledgeable about the issue. Adding requests for quick answers in the question title and body have a negative effect, hence my vote down.

Comment: Also, that's not HTML

Comment: You are right, and I read your comment and was going to remove the request for a quick answer, but Brandon beat me to it.

Comment: It's jsp, but since jsp gets converted to html, it is html.   By that, I mean that the names are in fact html.  Or maybe not, maybe that's my problem.

Comment: I think you'd get a much faster answer if you showed us some of the HTML that's generated, because quite honestly the jsp is obscuring what's going on for me. I'm also not sure what effect you're trying to achieve. How about a jsFiddle link?

Comment: These JSP questions are so rare; they actually make me feel at home :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem for me was the jsp reserves almost every settable variable.  Because of this, one cannot use name, or id, or anything like that to identify the checkboxes.  What I ended up doing was this:

JSP:

```
        <input type="checkbox" value="false"
            label="Select/Deselect All" title="-1"
            onclick="toggle(this, '-1')" />
        <br />
        <c:forEach items="${config.sources}" var="source"
            varStatus="sourceStatus">
            <form:checkbox path="sources[${sourceStatus.index}].selected"
                label="${source.sourceName}" title="${sourceStatus.index}"
                onclick="toggle(this, ${sourceStatus.index})" />
            <br />
            <c:forEach items="${source.feeds}" var="feed" varStatus="status">
                <c:if test="${feed.display == true }">  
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <form:checkbox
                        path="sources[${sourceStatus.index}].feeds[${status.index}].selected"
                        title="${sourceStatus.index}" />
                    <c:out value="${feed.name}" /> (provided by ${feed.provider})
                <br />
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
```

Javascript:

```
function toggle(chkbox, title) {
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var xIndex = 0;
    var x = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; ++i) {
        if((y[i] != null) && (y[i].title == title || title == -1)){
            x[xIndex] = y[i];
            xIndex++;
        }
    }
if (chkbox.checked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
            x[i].checked = true;
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
            x[i].checked = false;
        }
    } 
}
```

Title was the only editable field that jsp did not use I could find. Sad, I know, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. There's no need to test both "chkbox.checked" and "!chkbox.checked"; it's a boolean, so if it's not true, it's false.
2. Don't use "for ... in" loops. Those should be

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i)
   ```
3. To make a checkbox be checked, you should use

   ```
       x[i].checked = true;
       x[i].checked = false; // to make it un-checked
   ```